# TensorFlow variable with no initializer

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'd like to make a TensorFlow variable with no initializer at all, so that `tf.global_variables_initializer().run()` leaves that variable uninitialized.  Is there a clean way to do this?  All the APIs (`tf.Variable`, `tf.get_variable`, etc.) seem to take the value to assign as the initializer, so there's no obvious way to say "do nothing at all."

The motivation is a variable that should be initialized via synchronization over MPI with a `sess.run` call separate from normal initialization.  Any value computed locally is a bug, which is easy to find if no value is ever computed locally.

Comment: Did you consider using `tf.variables_initializer()` to initialize only part of your graph? Or is that of no help?´https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variables_initializer´

Comment: That's of no help, since there is a default initializer that applies even if you don't do `tf.variables_initializer`.